# Want to create worksheets in excel automatically

Tags: vba, excel

Basically I want to create something like an index, I want to link every sheet I create to the fist page which I named Main, tried to record some macros and then work with them but I realize i have no idea how to work with vb since I can´t make it work, since I only have a little knowledge in java I thought I could do something.
edit: My idea is to add automatically the pages I create to the index  (a column) whenever I create such sheet, *not* creating the index "after" finishing all the sheets.
Tried to hiperlink the page as soon as I created it and "create" a worksheet as soon as I typed something into a cell from a specific row. Any ideas how could I make it work? here are my two derpy attempts.

```
Sub Sheetcreation ()
    If (Sheets.Add(After)) = True Then [ Main.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    "Hoja1!A1", TextToDisplay:=(SheetName) ] [ Else [  ] ]
End Sub

Sub Sheetcreate ()
  Principal.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    "Hoja1!A1", TextToDisplay:=(SheetName)
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance guys, have a nice day.

Comment: Debra Dagleish has lots of info on hyperlinks. Here's some code that does what you want: http://www.contextures.com/excelhyperlinkfunction.html#tocvba

Comment: Thanks! I'll be checking it right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in the module for the sheet you want your links to reside in:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Value <> "" Then Call Module1.SheetCreation(Target.Value, Target.Item(1))
End Sub
```

Then put this code in an added module:

```
Sub SheetCreation(n As String, r As Range)
    ' Create the sheet
    Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = n
    r.Parent.Activate

    ' Add hyperlink
    r.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add _
        Anchor:=r, _
        Address:="", _
        SubAddress:="'" & n & "'!A1", _
        TextToDisplay:=n
End Sub
```

You'll notice that if you change the name of the procedure, or if your module is not named "Module1", you will have to change accordingly the code in `Worksheet_Change`.

Once the code is added, and changed if needed, you can type values into column A of the sheet you chose. The code will then create a new worksheet named after the value you inputted, and then create a hyperlink to that sheet.

Comment: This one looks pretty interesting and actually I understand it, but for some reason can't trigger it. should I give it a shortcut method? Still thank you.

Comment: Seems the only missing part in the code was the = True before the then, it works wonders!

Comment: There must be something funky with your Excel, the `= True` is absolutely not needed. It ran fine for me, I tested it with about 15 different links. But if you found a way to make it work, that's all that matters :)