# Create Hyperlink to sheet in cell VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have looked at many posts and cannot seem to get this right.  I have a userform that take a codename and then creates a sheet with that name, then adds a link to the new sheet as the last cell in Column B on another sheet.  I have used 3 different methods to insert the hyperlink, but all of them just return a blank cell, while if I change the value to any string, it works.

```
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim codename As String
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim cont As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    codename = InputBox("What is the codename?")


    Sheets("XXX").Visible = True
    Sheets("XXX").Copy After:=Worksheets("YYY")
    ActiveWindow.ActiveSheet.name = codename
    Sheets("XXX").Visible = False

    Worksheets(YYY).Activate
    lastrow = Sheets("YYY).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    ActiveSheet.Range("B" & lastrow).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveCell, Address:="", SubAddress:=sh & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=codename
    ActiveSheet.Range("B" & lastrow).End(xlUp).Offset(2).Activate
    ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveCell, Address:="", SubAddress:=sh.name & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=codename
    ActiveSheet.Range("B" & lastrow).End(xlUp).Offset(3) = codename
    ActiveSheet.Range("B" & lastrow).End(xlUp).Offset(4).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets(codename).Cells(1, 1), _
                  Address:="", SubAddress:=sh, TextToDisplay:=codename

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I know I have 4 iterations of essentially the same thing.  The point is is that no matter if I use 1 of them, or all 4, I get 3 blank cells and (codename) as plaintext, showing that I am obviously missing something easy that I for the life of me cannot figure out.  Thanks to all responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the links aren't working might be because you use the worksheet object `sh` without declaring it, and specifically, without declaring it as the new sheet.

In my solution I've only tested it using the `.Add` method that I included out-commented.

```
Sub test()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, nsh As Worksheet ' sh = YYY, nsh = codename
    Dim nrng As Range
    Dim codename As String
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim cont As Worksheet

    codename = InputBox("What is the codename?")

    Set sh = Sheets("YYY")

    Sheets("XXX").Visible = True
    Sheets("XXX").Copy After:=Worksheets("YYY")
    ActiveWindow.ActiveSheet.Name = codename
    Sheets("XXX").Visible = False
    'Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = codename ' if needed

    sh.Activate
    lastrow = sh.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    sh.Hyperlinks.Add _
        Anchor:=sh.Range("B" & lastrow), _
        Address:="", _
        SubAddress:="'" & codename & "'!A1", _
        TextToDisplay:=codename
End Sub
```

Shamelessly stolen from [myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36932431/4604845).

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Tester()

    DoHyperlink Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F10"), _
           Sheets("Sheet 2").Range("E12"), _
           "Click Me"

End Sub

'assumes rngFrom and rngTo are in the same workbook...
Sub DoHyperlink(rngFrom As Range, rngTo As Range, LinkText As String)

    rngFrom.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rngFrom, Address:="", _
            SubAddress:="'" & rngTo.Parent.Name & "'!" & rngTo.Address(), _
            TextToDisplay:=LinkText

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you are trying to do this... But don't understand why it's "YYY" (not dynamic).

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddSheetAndLinkIt()
    Dim codename As String
    Dim oWS As Worksheet, oRng As Range

    codename = InputBox("What is the codename?")
    ' Check if codename already exists
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(codename)
    If Not oWS Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The worksheet for """ & codename & """ already exists! You cannot create it again.", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Copy worksheet "XXX" and add hyperlink to "YYY"
    Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YYY")
    Set oRng = oWS.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("XXX").Copy After:=oWS
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("XXX (2)")
        .Name = codename
        .Visible = True
        .Activate
    End With
    oWS.Hyperlinks.Add oRng, "", "'" & codename & "'!A1", "Go to " & codename, codename
    Set oRng = Nothing
    Set oWS = Nothing
End Sub
```